# Cannot get data from collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get data from collection i am getting following two arrays in collection when i run this code:

```
{{ dd($child_categories->children) }}
```

[image]

### [image]

when i dump dd($child_categories i get :

[image]

and i want to get data through loop for that i am using following code:

> Code:
>
> Category_repository:

```
public function getChildCategories($id)
{
    return Category::with('children')->find($id); 
}
```

> Category Model:

```
   public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

> Category Controller:

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->findBySlug($slug);
        $child_categories=$this->categoryRepository->getChildCategories($category->id); 
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('category','child_categories'));
    }
```

> View:

```
 @foreach ($child_categories as $index => $element)
  {{$element->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what was the error then ?

Comment: after implementing what @BKF has given i'm getting following error:Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: what is the return of this $child_categories ?

Comment: you want to iterate only that two arrays ?

Comment: there can be unlimited arrays

Comment: whats the return of your child_categories ?

Comment: It is returning categories, added screenshot for child_categories return type value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you show function in this line :

```
$child_categories=$this->categoryRepository->getChildCategories($category->id)->get();
```

Then try:

```
@foreach ($child_categories->children as $element)
  {{$element->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok, post the code where we can get children from child_categories

Comment: Updated, check the answer

Comment: will get function will work here in show function or i have to update in category_repository